# Why is WebAPI Throwing a 'No MediaTypeFormatter' Error?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a strange issue happening with my WebAPI controller.

In my development environment (Win7, IIS 7.5) the method on the controller is called and the result is returned as expected.

In my integration environment (WIn Server 2003, IIS 6.0) I have deployed the code by copying it from my development box to the integration box. The method on the controller is called and returns the following error:

> "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type "EmailQueueResult"
>   from content with media type "text/html"."

What I don't understand is why I only get this error in my integration environment and not in my development environment.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]EmailQueueMessage email)
    {
        EmailQueueResult result;

        if (email != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var emailQueueIdList = QueueEmails(email);

                QueueAttachments(email, emailQueueIdList);

                foreach(var emailQueueId in emailQueueIdList)
                {
                    UpdateEmailQueueDateQueued(emailQueueId, DateTime.Now);
                }

                result = new EmailQueueResult(0, "Email added to queue.", "", null);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                result = new EmailQueueResult(2, "Error occurred.", e.Message, null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = new EmailQueueResult(1, "Email passed in was null.", "", null);
        }

        return ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, "application/json");
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
namespace App_Start
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "ControllerWithBooleanParameter",
                "api/{controller}/{showSentEmails}",
                null,
                new { boolConstraint = new IsBoolean() }
            );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "ControllerWithIntegerParameter",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                null,
                new { id = @"^\d+$" }
            );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "Default",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.net>
        <settings>
            <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
        </settings>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="address@email.com">
                <network host="smtp.server.com" port="25" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have also tried having this method just return a straight EmailQueueResult, and that gave me the same results.

EDIT:
Here are some more tests that I tried along with their results:

- When I send a POST request to the web service on my local machine using an external tool it works as expected.
- When I execute code that calls the web service using my local copy of the code it works as expected.
- When I send a POST request to the web service on the integration machine using an external tool it works as expected.
- When I execute code that calls the web service using the integration machine I get the above error.

The line of code that sends the POST:

```
        EmailQueueResult result = PostToWebService<EmailQueueMessage, EmailQueueResult>(EmailQueueBaseAddress, "application/json", EmailQueueUrlToCall, emailQueueMessage);
```

The PostToWebService method that actually makes the call:

```
    protected returnType PostToWebService<dataType, returnType>(string baseAddress, string mediaType, string urlToCall, dataType data)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(mediaType));

        MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

        HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<dataType>(data, jsonFormatter);

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(urlToCall, content).Result;

        returnType result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<returnType>().Result;

        return result;
    }
```

**UPDATE**: I installed the website and web service on a 2008 server. The only combination that fails seems to be when the web service on the 2003 box is called from the website on the 2003 box (2003 site -> 2003 service). The other three combinations (2008 site - > 2008 service, 2008 site -> 2003 service, 2003 site -> 2008 service) all seem to be working correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using the content type as 'application/json; charset=utf-8', ?
Use fiddler to figure out the exact issue.

Comment: Can you show your config?  That error does not look related to that code at all.  Do you have any MessageHandlers or global action filters installed?  Also, you may want to install the Web API tracing nugget to get more details

Comment: @Rifaj - The content type of the response is set to "application/json". I can add the "charset=utf8" part and see if that helps.

Comment: @DarrelMiller - I have added the WebApiConfig.cs and web.config, as requested.

Comment: That error makes no sense based on your posted code.  Try searching your code for "MyType"

Comment: Try changing your default route to "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Comment: As my testing indicates, it works in three out of four cases, so I don't think the route is the issue, or even the specific type. If either of those were the case I would think it wouldn't work anywhere, ever.

Comment: @DarrelMiller - That's what is making this error so frustrating. There doesn't seem to be any reason for it.

Comment: I edited to change the type in the error message to be the actual type I am seeing in the message. It matches the type of the data returned from the Post method.

Comment: Are you sure it says "EmailQueueResult" and not "EmailQueueMessage"  The error seems to be related to what you are POSTing, not what is being returned.  Can you show the code you are using to send the POST?

Comment: @DarrelMiller - added the code that POSTs to the service.

Comment: @nikeaa - are you using a custom media type formatter? if yes, could you share what are the supported media types on it

Comment: @KiranChalla - I am NOT using any custom media type formatters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it turns out this had NOTHING to do with the code, as some of you have expressed above. Basically, I had to change the local loopback address (127.0.0.1) in my hosts file on the 2003 box to the actual IP of the 2003 box and everything works as expexted now. Go figure.

Comment: Actually, this occurred because the web service being called didn't respond, so it was returning a 500 error, which was HTML formatted, and since it wasn't set up to recognize HTML, the error came up. By intercepting invalid HTTP response codes and returned in properly formatted message, this issue was resolved.

Comment: The answer in the comments was the issue I ran into when a Web API route changed on me.