# ApiController and Controller in a single project route conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes, asp.net-apicontroller

I have 2 controllers( and ApiController and a Controller). My ApiController calls a provider to get data from the database while my Controller returns a view. I have created separate route configs for them. However, it seems like it is having problems on identifying which route to use? I'm not really sure

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class WebApiApplication
{
    protected void ApplicationStart()
    {   
        WebApiAuthConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    }
}
```

The routes work fine when accessing within the project. However, when the HttpClient tries to contact the ApiController using the route stated above (Api/../..), it could not contact the controller. It seems like it's confused with the route.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting up the standard web routing in the WebApi portion of the code, consider doing it the other way around, setting up WebApi routing in the standard web routing portion of the code. This works in a project I have access to:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {
   protected void Application_Start() {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
      RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
      ...
   }
}

public class RouteConfig {
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
      );
   }
}

public static class WebApiConfig {
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Inverting the registration order did the trick, that is, the `ApiController` routes first and then the `Controller` routes. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You might find it better to factor out your API into a separate project. You might then also need to factor out a common data access project that your Web and API projects both depend upon but the resulting rationalized structure will make it easier to resolve config issues of the sort you describe and build failures in one area e.g. API will not stop other projects building.

Answer (score -1):

In WebApiConfig.cs, your routeTemplate should be `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Comment: Hi jksemple, even if I placed the {action} into the routeTemplate. I still get the same error of "No MediaTypeFormatter".

Comment: If you are getting NoMediaTypeFormatter error your problem may be similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455139/why-is-webapi-throwing-a-no-mediatypeformatter-error When you create your HttpClient what BaseAddress are you giving it and is that a resolvable Url on your server?

Comment: In your No MediaTypeFormatter message what type of object is it  trying to read and what media type is it expecting?

Comment: It's getting a 'text/html' but HttpClient is expecting an 'aaplication/json'

Comment: So maybe it's trying to return an error message rather than the result you expected. Try tracing the controller method.

Comment: What do you see if you use a browser to access the api endpoint url instead of your HttpClient?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455139/why-is-webapi-throwing-a-no-mediatypeformatter-error?lq=1